# Efficient way to compute number of visits in an IP range and time range

Tags: c, performance, web-services, algorithm

Assume there is a popular web server, the number of visits to this web server can be tens of thousands in an hour, in order to analyse the statistical property of these visits, we want to know the number of requests in a specific time range and IP range.

For example, we have 10<sup>12</sup> requests in the following format:

(IP address , visiting time)

Suppose we want to know how many visits came from the IP range [10.12.72.0 , 10.12.72.255] during 2p.m and 4p.m.

The only candidate ideas i can think of are:

(1)use B-TREE to index this large data set using one dimension, for instance build a B-TREE on the parameter IP. Using this B-TREE we can quickly get the number of request coming from any specific IP range, but how can we know how many of these visits are between 2p.m and 4p.m?

(2)use BITMAP, but similar to B-TREE, due to space requirement the BITMAP can only be built on one dimension, for instance IP address, we don't know how many of these request are issued between 2p.m and 4p.m.

Is there any efficient algorithm, thx? The number of queries can be quite large

Comment: Have you considered using MapReduce for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is figure out the precision you need...

TIME:

- Do you need, to the millisecond, time stamps or is, to the hour, good enough?
- - Number of hours since 1970 can fit in under a million, 3 bytes ~integer
- - Number of milliseconds and you need 8 bytes ~long

IP:

- Are all your IPs v4 (4 bytes) or v6 (16 bytes)?
- Will you ever search by specific IP or will you only use IP ranges?
- - If the latter you could just use the class C for each IP 123.123.123.X (3 bytes)

Assuming:

- 1 hour time precision is good enough
- 3 byte IP class C is good enough

Re-Organizing your data (2 possible structures pick one):

Database:

- You can use a relational database
- - Table: Hits
- - - IPClassC INT  NON-CLUSTERED INDEX
- - - TimeHrsUnix INT  NON-CLUSTERED INDEX
- - - Count BIGINT  DEFAULT VALUE (1)

Flat Files:

- You can use more flat files
- - Have 1 flat file for each class C IP that appears in your logs (max 2^24)
- - - Each file is 8B (big int) * 1MB (Hrs Since 1970 to 2070) = 8MB in size

How to load your new data structure:

Database:

- Parse your logs (read in memory one line at a time)
- Convert record to 3 byte IP and 3 byte Time
- Convert your IP class C to an integer and your Time hrs to an integer
- IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Hits WHERE IPClassC = @IP AND TimeHrsUnix = @Time)
- - UPDATE Hits SET Count = Count + 1 WHERE IPClassC = @IP AND TimeHrsUnix = @Time
- Else
- - INSERT INTO Hits VALUES(@IP, @Time)

Flat Files:

- Parse your logs (read in memory one line at a time)
- Convert record to 3 byte IP and 3 byte Time
- Convert your IP to a string and your time to an integer
- if File.Exist(IP) = False
- - File.Create(IP)
- - File.SetSize(IP, 8 * 1000000)
- CountBytes = File.Read(IP, 8 * Time, 8)
- NewCount = Convert.ToLong(CountBytes) + 1
- CountBytes = Convert.ToBytes(NewCount)
- File.Write(IP, CountBytes, 8 * Time, 8)

Querying your new data structures:

Database:

- SELECT SUM(Count) FROM Hits WHERE IPClassC BETWEEN @IPFrom AND @IPTo AND TimeHrsUnix BETWEEN @TimeFrom AND @TimeTo

Flat File:

- Total = 0
- Offset = 8 * TimeFrom
- Len = (8 * TimeTo) - Offset
- For IP = IPFrom To IPTo
- - If File.Exist(IP.ToString())
- - - CountBytes = File.Read(IP.ToString(), Offset, Len)
- - - LongArray = Convert.ToLongArray(CountBytes)
- - - Total = Total + Math.Sum(LongArray)
- Next IP

Some extra tips:

- If you go the database route your likely going to have to use multiple partitions for the database file
- If you go the flat file route you may want to break your query into threads (assuming your SAS will handle the bandwidth). Each thread would handle a sub set of the IP/Files in the range. Once all threads completed the totals from each would be summed.

Answer (score 2):

You want a data structure that supports [orthogonal range counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching).

Comment: can orthogonal range counting support this huge data set?

Comment: @outlaw Orthogonal range counting is the accepted name in the CS literature for the problem you're trying to solve. I don't have first-hand experience with particular data structures that support it.

Answer (score 0):

10^12 is a large number (TERA) - certainly too large for in-memory processing.
I would store this in a relational database with a star schema, use a time dimension, and pre-aggregate by time of day (e.g. hour bands), IP subnets, and other criteria that you are interested in.